# How to make re.search look for multiple patterns?

Tags: python, regex

Hello currently reading a book about regular expressions and i am stuck at this Task.

c) Match strings if it doesn’t contain white-space or the string error between the strings qty and price

```
str1 = '23,qty,price,42'
str2 = 'qty price,oh'
str3 = '3.14,qty,6,errors,9,price,3'
str4 = 'qty-6,apple-56,price-234
```

I figured out how to check the strings for not containing white space and not having error in between qty and price but i can´t combine both.

```
bool(re.search(r"^[^ ]+$",str1))
bool(re.search(r"(qty((?!error).)*price)",str1))
```

My question is how would `re.search` have to look like if i want to check for both requirements?

Comment: You basically ask for `^\S*?qty(?:(?!qty|error)\S)*?price\S*$`. However, the pattern is not quite efficient and with longer strings, you may expect slowdowns. It is better to resort to string operations as you do not seem to need any regex special things like word boundaries.

Comment: looks like I didn't word the exercise properly.. need to return `True` if input contains `qty` followed by `price` but `False` if there is a `whitespace` or `error` in between `qty` and `price`.. so something like `a qty-6,apple-56,price-234` will be `True`

Comment: Your approach is wrong, have you finally got something working? `^\S*qty(?:(?!error).)*?price\S*$` won't work, see https://regex101.com/r/bUbB0k/1, where `3.14,qty,6,errors,9,price,3qty price` matches but it should not.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to write a regexp that matches when the string contains either, and then invert the result with the `not` operator.

```
if not re.search(r"\s|qty.*error.*price", str1):
```